# how to type a higher-order NextPage component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a higher order component (HOC) that I use for auth purposes. I am converting this to a TypeScript friendly component. This is what I currently have:

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { useAccount } from 'wagmi';

import { useAppSelector } from '../../hooks';
import EmptyState from '../EmptyState/EmptyState';

const withAuth = Component => {
  const AuthenticatedComponent: NextPage = () => {
    const currUser = useAppSelector(state => state.auth);
    const { isConnected } = useAccount();
    {
      return currUser.address && isConnected ? <Component /> : <EmptyState />;
    }
  };

  return AuthenticatedComponent;
};

export default withAuth;
```

And how I'd normally call it:

```
const Proposal: NextPage<{ proposalTags: ProposalTag[] }> = ({ proposalTags }) => { /** code here **/}

export default withAuth(Proposal);
```

The problem I'm having is the linter is complaining `Parameter 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I am not entirely sure how to type `withAuth` in this case for the `Component` argument.

I want to be able to pass it an instance of `NextPage`, which may or may not contain an assortment of props of different types of their own as you can see an example of my `Proposal` page above.

Comment: You don't pass anything to the component when you render it with `<Component />`. What if the component needs props?

Comment: It does get props from server-side rendering, not entirely sure how to handle it in this case

Comment: Can't really give any answers if the problem has some holes in it

Comment: the components I plan to use this HOC will be able to take any number of props of any type. I do realize my bug above in that I never pass the Proposal component to withAuth with its respective props (proposalTags). so I need to figure out how to properly invoke `withAuth` and how to type it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic to infer the prop types, then in the new component, pass those props to the component:

```
import { ComponentType } from "react";

function withAuth<P>(Component: ComponentType<P>) {
  const AuthenticatedComponent: NextPage<P & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes> = (props) => {
    const currUser = useAppSelector(state => state.auth);
    const { isConnected } = useAccount();
    {
      return currUser.address && isConnected ? <Component {...props} /> : <EmptyState />;
    }
  };

  return AuthenticatedComponent;
};
```

We need `JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` in case the component is a "built-in" like `div`, `p`, etc.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQxXYW)

Comment: I will try this, more importantly, will try to understand it. Should I be invoking `withAuth` differently than I do in my original question for the Proposal component, making the passing of props explicit?

Comment: Nope, you just call it how you would: `withAuth(Proposal)`. In this case it's equivalent to `withAuth<{ proposals: ProposalTag[] }>(Proposal)` because TypeScript can and will infer the type of props `Proposal` expects. See the playground I linked.

Comment: also is 'ReactComponent' the correct import name? it's possibly a Next.js thing, but it says 'react' has no exported member named 'ReactComponent'

Comment: Oh sorry, it's supposed to be `ComponentType`. Again, the playground has the right and working code, I just somehow typed the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks it works, now I will try to spend time studying why it works